# Barra de rolagem em uma table com bootstrap

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap, linq

Tenho uma table, onde carrego informações do banco de dados nela. Ela tem duas colunas(CNPJ e Razão Social). A table eu montei com bootstrap. Gostaria que ela tivesse um height máximo e criasse barra de rolagem(acho ser difícil isso), pois não vejo como trabalhar com grid e mvc. Existe essa possibilidade? Existe uma consulta aqui a pedido da chafia, para trazer tudo(imagine a loucura disso) do BD. E aí a tabela fica de uma tamanho enorme.

Comment: +1 fica uma nota: com Bootstrap, coisas dinâmicas como barras de *scroll* e tamanhos adaptáveis costumam ser coisas simples de fazer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simples, no html faça assim:

```
<div class="table-overflow">
  <table>
   ...
  </table>
</div>
```

No CSS

```
.table-overflow {
    max-height:400px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Basta implementar ao seu gosto.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RVG5L/)**